# How to call included php file with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am not sure if this is best approach, but how to make AJAX call with included file? Let me make working simple example.

I have, main index.php file, with following content, where I want to access all data returned from included file where magic happens. Data is array type in reality.

```
<?php
require_once('magic.php');
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="variable" id="variable" />
     <input type="submit" value="Do magic" name="submit"  />
</form> 
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And "magic.php" file, where all the magic happens.

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
function doMagic($variable) {
    # do some magic with passed variable ...
    # and return data
    return $data;
}
$data = doMagic($variable);
# now return $data variable so main file can use it
return $data;
?>
```

What I want to do is to call this function doMagic() with AJAX, but all logic is already included and available in global space, and return $data to modal or pop-up window.

What is best approach, because I am already passing variable to included file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ajax` like the following

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     $.ajax({url: "magic.php", 
     data: {variable : $'#variable').val()},
     success:function(data){console.log(data);});
});
```

and in `magic.php`, use `json_encode`

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
function doMagic($variable) {
    # do some magic with passed variable ...
    # and return data
    return $data;
}
$data = doMagic($variable);
# now return $data variable so main file can use it
return json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Than in that case, I don't have to include magic.php file, because I will pass and recieve data with AJAX? Only reason to include magic.php in index.php is to make functions globally available to index.php, and to submit form without redirection to action page (magic.php).

Comment: @AlanKis, exactly, you dont have to inlude magic.php in the first file if you are not using variables/functions from that file. As for submitting without redirect, thats a different story, you need to return false in onsubmit. Let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: JS confuses me a little bit, but just for now. Form action is now "<form action="magic.php" method="POST">" I have added return false at the end of submit(), but it still redirect me to blank magic.php file. I will try to make some fiddle somewhere.

Comment: here is pastebin link. PHP Fiddle is uselles as we loging data to console. http://pastebin.com/qSRs2M8T

Comment: @AlanKis, put return false in the last line of the submit handler.

Comment: see ediit: http://pastebin.com/qSRs2M8T. It seems that JS throws error in console.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `jQuery` as a tag...

You could do something like this:

In your index.php:

```
<input type="text" id="variable">
<div id="#myButton"></div>
<div id="#response"></div>
```

Then have a Javascript file (or include in your index.php):

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var myVariable = $('#variable').val();
    $.post( "magic.php",{variable: myVariable}, function(data) {
        $( "#response" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

This basically means, when you click the item that has the id of `myButton`, it'll grab the value of what's inside of the input with the id of `variable`, POST that via [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to your `magic.php` file, and return the data. Then, it replaces the html of the div with the id of `response` with the data it returns.

Just make sure to include the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/)