# Php and jquery auto DOM update

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am fetching data in an array format from a file called `get.php` to `index.Php`, using ajax request, the ajax request is been process every 5 second with a JavaScript function `Setinterval()`, so I want to change the patten, to including the `get.Php` file in the `index.Php` file, then write a jquery code that check if the array has increase or not.

So if the array file have increase then I want to auto update the array.

Comment: If you get result from get.php via ajax there's no point including it unless there are some variables you need access to on index.php load. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429006/2463644

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but my question have not been answered well. how would the array be update automatically. just as how React works. i want the array to be updated if there is a change  without reloading the page or submitting any form??.

Answer (score 1):

Set session variable in get.php holding array length and compare it to array length at each ajax call

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['length']) {
    $_SESSION['length'] = 0;
}
if ($_SESSION['length'] != count($array)) {
    $_SESSION['length'] = count($array);
    //iterate over array and prepare data in form of html
    //that will be sent via ajax and displayed on index.php
    echo $data;
}
```

In index.php

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get.php',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#output').html(data);
        }
    }
});
```